# let $a,b,c \in\mathbb{R} ,a<3$ and all roots $p(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ be negative . then prove that $b+c\neq 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> let $a,b,c \in\mathbb{R} ,a<3$ 
>   and all roots $p(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ be negative . 
>   then prove that $b+c\neq 4$
>   MyTry :

we have $x_1<0 ,x_2<0,x_3<0$
So:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=\dfrac{-a}{1}=-a \to a\in (0,3)$$
and :

$$x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3=\dfrac{-c}{1}=-c$$

now what ?

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $y_i=-x_i$, so that all the $y_i$ are non-negative. We know $b=y_1y_2+y_2y_3+y_3y_1, c=y_1y_2y_3$. Then by [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) we have $$b=y_1y_2+y_2y_3+y_3y_1\leq \frac13 (y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2+2y_1y_2+2y_2y_3+2y_3y_1)\leq\frac13 (y_1+y_2+y_3)^2<3$$

so $b+c<4$.

Comment: sorry . i want $b+c\neq 4$

Comment: Well, if the sum is less than 4, then it is certainly not equal to 4.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$\frac{|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{|x_1|\cdot|x_2|\cdot |x_3|}$$

Comment: why $\frac{|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{|x_1|\cdot|x_2|\cdot |x_3|}$?

Comment: This is a basic inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means