# $x^{3}+ax^2+bx+c$ has all roots negative real numbers and a<3. Establish an inequality between only b and c

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, cubics

> A cubic equation $x^{3}+ax^2+bx+c$ has all negative real roots and $a, b, c\in R$ with $a<3.$
>
> Prove that $b+c<4.$

My attempt :

Let the cubic be $f(x)$

Plotting graph we see that ,

$f(x\geq 0)>0$.

So we can see that a relation between $a, b, c$ can be established by putting $x=1$, so,

$1+a+b+c> 0$.

So $b+c>-4$.

Also by using *Vieta's Formula* we get $a, b, c > 0$.

Now I'm uncertain how to proceed, any help will be appreciated. This is a problem of a maths olympiad. Thanks.

Comment: Could you reveal which olympiad is it?

Comment: @VIVID the question had a tag of Pre-RMO. The question, instead of proving, asks for the maximum value of expression

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1714027p11064957.

Comment: Also solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2314073/42969.

Comment: Yes, so I have marked it as duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $-p,-r,-q$ be it roots, so $p,q,r>0$.  Now by Vitea formulas we have $$p+r+q =a < 3$$ and $$b+c = pr+pq+qr +qpr$$

So we need to check if $$pr+pq+qr +qpr<4$$

By Am-Gm ineaquality we have $$pqr \leq ({p+q+r\over 3})^3 < 1$$

It is easy to check that (say with Cauchy inequality) $$p^2+q^2+r^2\geq pq+pr+qr$$ so $$(p+q+r)^2\geq 3(pq+pr+qr)$$ and thus $$pq+pr+qr \leq 3$$ so $$pq+pr+qr +pqr< 3+1=4$$

and we are done.

Comment: Is it correct to use am gm inequality by using substitution like this. If so, can you please elaborate why.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what are you asking.

Comment: 1 :I mean if we have negative numbers $x_1, x_2.....x_n$, we can make then equal to $-a_1,-a_2.....-a_n$ then calculate Am Gm inequality of $a_1,a_2....a_n$?  2: And most importantly can we substitute the value of $a_1....a_n$ back as $x_1.... x_n} after evaluating the AM GM  inequality

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Is the 2nd part of my above comment that I have edited right now also correct?

Comment: ie x1=-a1, x2=-a2 after we have solved the inequality

Answer (score 1):

We can write our polynomial in the form $(x+r_1)(x+r_2)(x+r_3)$, where $r_i$ are positive real numbers. Note that $b=r_1r_2+r_2r_3+r_3r_1$ and $c=r_1r_2r_3$.

---

---

---

$\color{Green}{\text{Maybe you will find}}$ [Maclaurin's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality) $\color{Green}{\text{very interesting}}$.

By [Maclaurin's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality), we know that $\sqrt[3]{S_3} \leq \frac{S_1}{3}$, 
or equivalently: 
$$c=r_1r_2r_3 = S_3 \leq (\frac{S_1}{3})^3 = (\frac{a}{3})^3 \leq (\frac{3}{3})^3=1.$$

---

Also again by use of [Maclaurin's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality), we know that $\sqrt[2]{\frac{S_2}{3}} \leq \frac{S_1}{3}$, 
or equivalently: 
$$b=r_1r_2+r_2r_3+r_3r_1 = S_2 \leq 3(\frac{S_1}{3})^2 = 3(\frac{a}{3})^2 \leq 3(\frac{3}{3})^3=3.$$

---

so $$b+c \leq 1+3=4.$$

---

---

---

$\color{Red}{\text{Comment}}$: Also, you can obtain all of the above inequalities 
$\color{Red}{\text{only}}$ by using [AM–GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).